# Returned JSON not displaying a value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a jQuery script that returns JSON data and for some reason a specific value is not displayed and I don't know why since all the other properties are displayed fine. The value that is not working correctly is `data.code`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cos").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var produs_href = $(this).closest('.productinfo').find('a:first').attr('href');
        var id_prod = $(this).data('id');
        var color = $(this).closest(".col-sm-4").find(".selected").data("color");

        if (typeof color === 'undefined') {
            alert ("selecteaza o culoare!");
        } else {
            $.getJSON(href + '&color=' + color).done(function(data) { 
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $("#cnt").empty();
                    $("#cnt").append('' + val.cnt + '');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/engine/shop/produse_cos_popup.php?id=" + id_prod + "&color=" + color,
                        type: "GET",  
                        datatype: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#qty').html('Cantitate: ' + data.qty + '');
                            $('.nr_prod').html('' + data.qty_total + 'produse în cosul dvs');
                            $('#nume').html('' + data.nume + '');
                            $('#pret').html('' + data.pret_total + '');

                            if (data.poza!='') {
                                $('.produs_img').html(data.poza);
                            } else {
                                $('.produs_img').html('<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/no_photo.jpg">');
                            }

                            $('#cod').html('<b>Cod Produs:</b ' + data.code + '');
                            $('#culoare').html('<b>Culoare:</b> ' + data.culoare + '');
                            $('#greutate').html('<b>Greutate:</b> ' + data.greutate +'');
                            $('#viteza').html('<b>Viteza maximă:</b> ' + data.viteza + '');
                            $('#autonomie').html('<b>Autonomie:</b> ' + data.autonomie + '');
                            $('#putere').html('<b>Putere motor:</b> ' + data.putere + '');
                            $('#detalii_prod').modal('show'); 
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the JSON returned. As you can see the variable `code` is there. It displays `Cod Produs: but without the value.

```
{
    "qty": "4",
    "poza": "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"images\/trotineta_verde.png\">",
    "id": "1",
    "nume": "Eco",
    "code": "etw1",
    "greutate": "10.7 kg",
    "viteza": "27 km\/h",
    "autonomie": "30 km",
    "putere": "350 Watt",
    "culoare": "verde",
    "pret_total": "37560",
    "qty_total": "18"
}
```

Comment: Use a different variable other than `data` here `success: function(data){` and then `console.log()` it to make sure you are getting what you expect.

Comment: omg i just notice why it's not working, i forgot to close </b .

Comment: haha just noticed that and wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the `</b`

Change

```
$('#cod').html('<b>Cod Produs:</b ' + data.code + '');
```

For

```
$('#cod').html('<b>Cod Produs:</b> ' + data.code + '');
```